# Python: MySQLdb library encoding issue

Tags: python, mysql

I have a mysql db. I set charset to utf8;

```
...
  PRIMARY KEY  (`username`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 | 
...
```

I connect to db in python with MySQLdb;

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host = "localhost",
                               passwd = "12345",
                               db = "db",
                               charset = 'utf8',
                               use_unicode=True)
```

When I execute a query, response is decoding with "windows-1254". Example response;

```
curr = conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
select_query = 'SELECT * FROM users'
curr.execute(select_query)

for ret in curr.fetchall():
    username = ret["username"]
    print "repr-username; ", repr(username)
    print "username; "username.encode("utf-8")
...
```

output is;

```
repr-username;  u'\xc5\u0178\xc3\xbckr\xc3\xbc\xc3\xa7a\xc4\u0178l\xc3\xbcli'
username;  ÅŸÃ¼krÃ¼Ã§aÄŸlÃ¼li
```

When I print username with "windows-1254" it works fine;

```
...
print "repr-username; ", repr(username)
print "username; ", username.encode("windows-1254")
...
```

Output is;

```
repl-username;  u'\xc5\u0178\xc3\xbckr\xc3\xbc\xc3\xa7a\xc4\u0178l\xc3\xbcli'
username;  şükrüçağlüli
```

When I try it with some other characters like cyrillic alphabet, decodeding is changed dinamicly. How can I prevent it?

Comment: to be clear, "şükrüçağlüli" is the output you want?

Comment: Yes. This text has some turkish special characters like "şüçğ".

Comment: Is that the charset of the table as well?

Comment: Terminal encoding ? Other idea: could you modify your test case to both `INSERT` and `SELECT` from Python. Does the problem persist ?

Comment: @Korem yes it is also set to utf-8. Sylvain terminal encoding is utf-8, too.

Comment: On my UTF-8 system `u"şükrüçağlüli" == u'\u015f\xfckr\xfc\xe7a\u011fl\xfcli'`. This is not what you have. Are you certain the data have been properly encoded at `INSERT` time ?

Comment: @Optox it throw UnicodeDecodeError.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the items where encoded wrong while INSERT to the database.

I recommend python-ftfy(from https://github.com/LuminosoInsight/python-ftfy) (helped me out in a simillar problem):

```
import ftfy

username = u'\xc5\u0178\xc3\xbckr\xc3\xbc\xc3\xa7a\xc4\u0178l\xc3\xbcli'
print ftfy.fix_text(username) # outputs şükrüçağlüli
```